# Re-evaluate directive attribute expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having troubles in re-evaluating an expression passed as attribute of a custom angular (1.2.28) directive.
I've tried all the possible combination of `$eval`, `$parse` as well as isolated and non-isolated scope. I can't wrap my mind around this.

I have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in dataset">
    <my-directive 
      show-tooltip="user.level=='visitor' && item.memberOnly" 
      content-tooltip="isAdded(item) && 'Remove Me' || 'Add Me'">
    <my-directive>
</div>
```

The problem is that `user.level` can change because for example the user logged in and the (enclosing) scope function `isAdded` can returns different values depending if the items was already added to a list or not.

The directive:

```
angular.module("MyModule", [])
    .directive("myDirective", () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            priority: 999,
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                showTooltip = scope.$eval(attrs.showTooltip);
                contentTooltip = scope.$eval(attrs.contentTooltip);

                // This works
                scope.$watch(attrs.contentTooltip, function(value) {
                    if( value and value != contentTooltip)
                        contentTooltip = value
                });

                // This never works
                scope.$watch(attrs.showTooltip, function(value) {
                    if( value and value != showTooltip)
                        showTooltip = value
                });

                // Do things..
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know why but the first watch will work, the second will never work. I've used a similar approach with $parse but couldn't get it to work either.
Maybe I'm doing this totally wrong

Answer (score 0):

Look into using attrs.[$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) instead:

```
attrs.$observe('showTooltip', function(){

})
```

Comment: The values passed to the attributes are not interpolated, so I can't use $observe, isn't it?

Comment: You can add them into your scope when you create the directive. `scope: { showToolTip: '@', contentTooltip: '@' }`